# Sort list of dictionaries according to key, value such that the only first three of the key, value pair should come in the given list of dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Sort the dict by the key 'ordering' if ordering is greater then that dict should appear first and then the dict which contain next greater ordering and the **first three** greater ordering dicts should be stored in the list.

Input:

```
my_list = [{u'item_group': u'Bits Special',
         u'item_name': u'Tool Bits-Metric',
         u'ordering': 1},
        {u'item_group': u'Performance Drills 3X',
         u'item_name': u'Drills-Short-Metric',
         u'ordering': 3},
        {u'item_group': u'Hand Taps',
         u'item_name': u'Shank-Metric',
         u'ordering': 4},
        {u'item_group': u'Tool Bits',
         u'item_name': u'T42-Square HSS Tool Bits-BSW',
         u'ordering': 2,}]
```

Expected o/p:

```
     op_list = [{u'item_group': u'Hand Taps',u'item_name': u'Shank-Metric',
           u'ordering': 4},{u'item_group': u'Performance Drills 3X',
           u'item_name': u'Drills-Short-Metric',u'ordering': 3}, 
          {u'item_group': u'Tool Bits',u'item_name': u'T42-Square HSS 
           Tool Bits-BSW',u'ordering': 2,}]
```

I've tried :

```
 for i in mylist:
       if i['ordering']>mylist['ordering']:
          op_list.append(i)
```

Comment: May I kindly suggest that you try a little bit harder? It's really an easy task if you take time to read the doc for `list.sort()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are examples showing how to sort a list, giving your own key to use for comparison. You need this revsered (i.e. descending) and then need to take the top three.

Simplifying what you have, consider

```
my_list=[{u'ordering':1}, {u'ordering':3}, {u'ordering':4}, {u'ordering':2}]
```

you can sort this:

```
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda d: d[u'ordering'], reverse=True)
[{'ordering': 4}, {'ordering': 3}, {'ordering': 2}, {'ordering': 1}]
```

and slice off what you need:

```
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda d: d[u'ordering'], reverse=True)[:3]
[{'ordering': 4}, {'ordering': 3}, {'ordering': 2}]
```